# Cannot log out of site

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

I'm trying to log off a site, but it always keeps me logged in. What I tried in chrome:

- Use incognito mode
- go to devtools - application - storage - clear site data (including 3rd party cookies)

If I refresh, I still see my information. There is a log out button, but it doesn't work.
My assumption is that it's using a SSO service or something but I don't know how to track it. And when I load a page there's like 50 requests and I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: so if its an SSO, then the domain for the auth system may be entirely different than the domain of the application that you are trying to log out of, so the cookies that are preserving your auth/sessions may not be visible until you browse to the SSO's domain itself.

Comment: Oho found it! Thank you! I had to preserve the network log because it was redirecting and I was not seeing it. Then, I want to the site and just nuked the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was SSO. What I did:

- Opened chrome dev tools
- Opened network tab and toggled on "preserve log" (or the redirects will clear the network calls)
- Checked all the domains on the Url (in my case it was of type document and not xhr)
- Opened the domains in another tab (1 by 1, there were not many and the request said SSO), and cleared the cookies on the application tab

Then, the site finally showed me the login screen (no more logged in).

[image: The toggle to preserve the log]